# Filter result from Get-ADUser using sAMAccountname

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to extract a username from AD using `Get-ADUser`. The issue I'm having is when using `sAMAaccount` name as filter, I get multiple results if the value is found in multiple entries. To illustrate, if my `samaccountname` is 'a123b', and my coworker's is 'c1234d', I get both our names when I run this:

```
get-aduser -ldapFilter "(samaccountname=*123*)"| select Name
```

I would like to return only my information based on '123' and not '1234'

I've already tried the following as well to no avail:

```
get-aduser -Filter "samaccountname -like '*123*'" | select Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can narrow it down with a regular expression:

```
$filter = "[a-zA-Z]123[a-zA-Z]"
Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -like '*123*'" | where { $_.samaccountname -match $filter} | select name
```

- `$filter` is a simple regex pattern looking for 123 surrounded by letters (uppercase or lowercase)
- `-match` is the operator that allows a regex comparison

Answer (score 3):

When using a *partial* SamAccountName in a Filter or LDAPFilter, it is more than likely to get multiple results.

To test and return a specific user account, you need the filter to be more specific if possible (depends on what policies your environment uses for accountnames), like

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like 'a123*'" | Select-Object Name
```

or use an extra `Where-Object` clause to narrow down the results by some other user property like the firstname for instance:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*123*'" | Where-Object { $_.GivenName -eq 'John' } | Select-Object Name
```

Mind you, the above examples can still return multiple user objects..

If you have it, the absolute sure way of retrieving a single user object is by using the `DistinghuishedName` of that user and get the object by using the `-Identity` parameter. See [Get-ADUSer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser)

<sup>P.S.:
When using the `-like` operator or an LDAPFilter, use wildcard characters on the parts of the name that can vary.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot use any other filter because I'm strictly using samccountname to look for user information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use regex in the LDAP query, you could use a query like this to tell it to find user accounts that contain `123` but not with a fourth digit:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*123*)(!samaccountname=*1231*)(!samaccountname=*1232*)(!samaccountname=*1233*)(!samaccountname=*1234*)(!samaccountname=*1235*)(!samaccountname=*1236*)(!samaccountname=*1237*)(!samaccountname=*1238*)(!samaccountname=*1239*)(!samaccountname=*1230*))
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Note that, if you have a filter that starts with a wildcard, the index for that attribute cannot be used, so it will have to look at *every* account to find a match. I added a filter for `objectClass`, since that is indexed and it will ensure it only looks at user objects.

Comment: I see what you're trying to achieve, and I believe this will work as well. However, the solution provided by Itchydon suits our needs better. But I appreciate you looking into my question!

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that the other solution will ask AD for more accounts than you need, loading them all into memory, then discarding some of the results. Whereas this solution will only ask for what you need. If you are filtering out very few accounts, then it won't matter. But if you are filtering our 10's or 100's of accounts, then it will be a bigger difference in speed.

Comment: Got it, I didn't even think of the potential performance hit when filtering out more accounts. For now, the script I have is very limited in scope so the other solution works. But for future reference, I will look into your solution as a viable alternative. Thanks again!